# Android Jacoco Please supply original non-instrumented classes

Tags: android, jacoco, dagger-hilt

Trying to add Hilt to current project which already has Jacoco running.

I'm seeing below error log (code is compiled and runs OK.)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process instrumented class (path masked)/DescVm$special$$inlined$map$3. Please supply original non-instrumented classes.
```

So I'm trying to `supply original non-instrumented classes` as the error message says, but I don't know how to.

I've done searches and found:

1. There is `restore-instrumented-classes` option for maven jacoco plugin, is it also available for gradle jacoco plugin? If so, could someone please let me know? (I think [this article](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/958) is highly related to my question)
2. [This option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299155/kotlin-jacoco-illegalclassformatexception-please-supply-original-non-instrume) seems like I have to entirely give up jacoco's coverage so I'm not tempted to do so. Am I mistaken?
3. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378618/kotlin-jacoco-no-coverage-illegalclassformatexception-please-supply-orig) seems like unrelated to mine as I'm not on a multi-module project.

info:

android gradle plugin version: 7.0.4

gradle version: 7.0.2

jacoco version: 0.8.7

hilt version: 2.38.1

Thank you.

Comment: A bit old, but I am having the same issue. My "work around" has been to run maven clean and install. After that success, I am able to run the Jacoco command what was causing this error. However anytime I update the project in any way, to run the coverage report I have to clean/install again.